# SQL query to determine the column based on count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with writing a SQL query on a purchase table and changing the 'item' column to 'Multi' if multiple items were purchased on the same day:

Heres the sample table:

```
name | date       | item 
-------------------------
Jack | 20120105   |  TV
Jack | 20120105   |  Table
Jack | 20120105   |  Chair
Ryan | 20170822   |  TV
Roma | 20190525   |  TV
Bill | 20110121   |  Table
```

Jack in the above table for example has multiple purchases on same day so would like to result to be 'Multi' for 'item' column:

```
name | date       | item 
-------------------------
Jack | 20120105   |  Multi
Ryan | 20170822   |  TV
Roma | 20190525   |  TV
Bill | 20110121   |  Table
```

This query works but what if there are more than 2 items purchased by same person on same day:

```
select name
       case when p1.item <> p2.item then 'U'
             else p1.item
             end as item_name
from purchases p1 join purchases p2 on (p1.name = p2.name)
```

Any other better ways to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This query you shared does not work. 1. select name and then you are missing comma 2. select name is not possible because you are selecting from two tables where there is a column name in this tables. 3. In your results you desire a "Multi" when more than one purchase and in your code you use simple "U". 4. In the query there is not date column but there is one in the results 5. In the query you have as "item_name" and in the results it is called "item"


Next time prepare the question little bit better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause with `SELECT DISTINCT` to change the `item` to `Multi` when more than one item is purchased on the same day:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, date,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM purchases p2 
                         WHERE p2.name  = p1.name
                           AND p2.date  = p1.date
                           AND p2.item != p1.item) THEN 'Multi'
            ELSE item 
        END AS item
FROM purchases p1
```

Another alternative would be to aggregate and check the `COUNT` of items bought by a person on a given day:

```
SELECT name, date, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Multi'
            ELSE MIN(item)
       END AS item
FROM purchases
GROUP BY name, date
```

In both cases the output is:

```
name    date        item
Jack    20120105    Multi
Ryan    20170822    TV
Roma    20190525    TV
Bill    20110121    Table
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ecd2f/2)

Comment: Thanks for the sql and the demo link!

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select name, date,
       (case when min(item) = max(item) then min(item)
             else 'Multi'
        end) as item_name
from purchases
group by name, date;
```

Comment: @user2727704 . . . If someone purchases one item multiple times on the same day, this probably does what you want.